# Why can't I use rg (ripgrep) in an Org mode source block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ripgrep

I have the following source block in my Org mode file:

```sh
#+begin_src sh :results output
  exec 2>&1
  mkdir -p /tmp/example && cd /tmp/example
  echo "hello" > world
  rg --color=never 'hello'
  :
#+end_src
```

However, I never see any output in Org mode. The same code works fine in my shell. I've also compared the `env`ironment of both the `org-babel-execute:shell` results and my shell and they seem to differ only in `TERM`.

Why doesn't `rg` output anything when I execute my block?

Comment: @Drew are you certain about that tag?

Comment: Nope - rolled back. Thx. (The tag should get a proper description. And it looks like there are two very different `rg` meanings.)

Comment: @Drew [I'm on it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/64365/revisions) for `ripgrep`. The other [tag:rg] is used on `rg.el` which uses `ripgrep` behind the scenes, so [tag:rg] might still be fine, but [tag:ripgrep] is more explicit, see also [my synonym proposal](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/583/make-rg-a-synonym-of-ripgrep)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely related to [this issue in ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/951). As you didn't specify any file pattern, `rg` also reads from `STDIN`. For some reason, this yields to no result at all in your example, probably because Org uses your script as input into a shell (`sh < your-sh-scode`).

However, if you use `/dev/null` or an explicit file pattern as input for `rg`, it works fine:

```sh
#+begin_src sh :results output
  exec 2>&1
  mkdir -p /tmp/example && cd /tmp/example
  echo "hello" > world
  rg --color=never 'hello' </dev/null
  :
#+end_src
```